# How to prove that $(L_1L_2)' = (L_2)'(L_1)'$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, automata, finite-automata

### How to prove that $(L_1L_2)' = (L_2)'(L_1)'$

$(L)'$ denotes the reverse of $L$.

I think using mathematical induction, it can be shown true for two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ of length $1$ each and then do induction using one of the lengths and then repeat with the other length. 
Is there any other way of proving this in a simpler way without making it too big with induction method?

Comment: Your notation suggests that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are languages, but then you refer to strings. What is the right interpretation?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Nothing is given in the book about it. I think language works fine if we look at it in a exhaustive manner.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in (L_1L_2)'$ then there exist $w_1 \in L_1$ and $w2\in L2$ such that $$x = \mathrm{reverse}(w1w2) = \mathrm{reverse}(w2) \mathrm{reverse}(w1) \in (L_2)'(L_1)'$$

All those statements work both ways, so you get that $x\in (L_1L_2)' \iff x\in (L_2)'(L_1)'$